# How can I get great views of the Bugaboos (Canada) in April?

Tags: sightseeing, canada, winter

After a long stay, I am going to be traveling back to the United States from British Columbia, CA in a few weeks. I would love to climb in the famous [Bugaboos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugaboos), but obviously that isn't practical in April, and my partner is injured. However, we don't want to pass up the opportunity to see the Bugaboos, which are supposed to be fantastic, and are an iconic climbing area. The Provincial Park website for the [Bugaboos](http://www.env.gov.bc.ca/bcparks/explore/parkpgs/bugaboo/) isn't very telling, aside from an indication that the road leading from Brisco, BC up to the Park is gravel and closed until "late spring."

I'd like to get some good views of the dramatic peaks in the area, specifically the Bugaboos, and possibly even take a short day-hike, so how can I do that? Are there any resources that anyone can provide?

[image: Bugaboo Spire at sunrise by BeiJiaLi]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want fantastic views, and money is not an object, then the answer is [Heli-hiking](http://www.canadianmountainholidays.com/heli-hiking/faq/what-is).

> Based from our remote mountain lodges, each day we take short helicopter flights to access some of the most spectacular mountain terrain in North America. We offer a variety of adventures to suit any traveller.

That link is just the first one I found, so I don't specifically recommend it. [These guys](http://www.panoramaresort.com/summer/activities/flightseeing-tours-hiking) I've flown with for heli-skiing. Most of these trips are offered from ski resorts, and do heli-skiing in the winter; they might still be in ski mode in April. You can probably book in for the helicopter trip only even if they are still doing skiing.

The view from the ski areas is also pretty fabulous. Some resorts have chalet's fairly high up the mountain, and gondola access to it, which means you don't need to ski to get there. [Sunshine Village is an example, though not in the Bugaboos](http://www.skibanff.com/sunshine-village/). If you can find one of those you will get great views. You might have to buy a ski pass, but at least that's cheaper than a helicopter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I emailed BC Parks and their response was,"The upper access road will be snow covered until late May at the earliest and only accessible by snowmobile or by skiing in. It is common for large piles of avalanche debris consisting of a mixture of snow, rock, and logs to block the access road until early to mid-June." So it seems that beyond skiing, a gondola ride or helicopter is the only choice.